# Pinching on mesh caused by supportive edges from detail on cylinder/sphere

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, topology

So I know quite a good bit about topology and from what I know so far is that fix is either using shrinkwrap, deformer, more geometry to start with or simply just get in zbrush, but is there really no way to achieve those kinds of shape with just low poly topology?

Here are some examples:

[image: Auto-Smooth]

[image: Subd+Support edges]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please show some examples?

Comment: Of course, I just added them.

Comment: yes sometimes you have no other choice than adding topology, but how does your topology look like?

Comment: Im not completely sure, but its as good as it can get in this case.(image added)

Comment: To be honest even with more geometry/topology it still creates this pinch on corner for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I could get starting with a 36 vertex cylinder, using shrinkwrap to a cylinder, and moving a bit the vertices. Not perfect but almost no pinching. I'm not sure you can get something good with less vertices.

[image]

[image]

Alternative:

[image]

[image]